# Images glitch out after suspending

Tags: suspend, 21.10, desktop-background

I have Ubuntu 21.10, after each sleep, the background glitches out like this:

[image]

Also, sometimes the application, WiFi, sound, some letters, and battery icons get glitched out as well.

After I installed the installer on my USB again, and reinstalled Ubuntu, the problem persisted. I gave it plenty of swap (2x the amount of RAM) and I replaced the Disk recently (new SSD)

My current theory is that the RAM is quite old, and the Hiber file might be getting corrupted

EDIT:
My GPU is a `Mobility Radeon HD 5730 / 6570M` on a laptop

EDIT 2:

Also the laptop in general is quite old.
I also replaced the old hard drive to a new SSD

Comment: It might be a display driver problem. Please, give details about your graphics card.

Comment: Also Im on a laptop